# Deleting a table passed into a function, within the function

Tags: variables, lua, lua-table

How can I set a table that I pass into a function to nil? When I try

```
local t = {}

function deleteTable(table)
    table = nil
end

deleteTable(t)
```

Nothing happens, `t` still points to a table value. Is there any way to set the table passed into a function to `nil` from within the function?

Edit: Not trying to delete the contents of the table, what I wanted was to remove a reference to a table from within a function so that the table would be garbage collected. I misspoke out of ignorance of what I was actually trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a table in Lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061733/how-to-delete-a-table-in-lua)

Comment: Also don't use `table` as an argument/variable. It overwrites the table library. This is bad practice.

Comment: @warspyking Did you mean hide/shadow?

Comment: @warspyking I wasn't aware of that, but I'm not using it in my code anyway; that function was just an example. Thanks.

Comment: @deduplicator I guess I should've wrote it as the it overwrites table library's variable, but yeah. You get the idea

Answer (score 2):

Simply said, you cannot set a table to `nil`:
A table is a table is a table.

What you *can* do is setting the variable or slot of a table pointing to said table to something else like `nil`.
There is no way (outside the debug-api) to refer to local variables, and you would need table and key to refer to a slot in a table.

But even then the table is only garbage-collected if *all* such references are gone, and not immediately.
Lua does not do manual memory-management, but lazy garbage-collection.

Comment: I see, so is there any way to set a given variable pointing to the table to nil using a function? I ask because the function in my program does other things aside from removing the reference to the table, and it would be tedious to call the function and then set the variable to nil afterwards each time I use the function.

There is only one variable referencing the table, and I don't need the table to get collected immediately, so that part isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution. Would this work for what I'm trying to do?

```
local t = {};

function removeReference(tab)
    --do stuff with tab

    return nil;
end

t = removeReference(t);
```

In the above example I could just do t = nil and not use a function, but in my program the function does other things with the table first; I just want it to end in removing the reference. So is this the best solution, or is there a more ideal way?

Comment: That works but why do you need to "remove the table"? t has has a scope. Can't you just let the table live until t goes out of scope?